# Error opening excel in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-4.0

I need to open excel file with `CorruptLoad` paramterer from powershell-script. But when I try to make it, I get an error `Exception calling "Open" with "15" argument(s): "open method workbooks class failed"`. This error occurs **only** when I call `Open` with all 15 arguments. And when I try to open the same excel file with `VB.net` program with 15 arguments or with specifying value of named argument `CorruptLoad`, there is no problem!

I'm using `powershell v 4.0`, Office 2010 with SP2 and `.NET Framework 4.5.2`.

Here is my `powershell` code:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
try
{
    $missing = [System.Type]::Missing
#   $wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open("d:\temp\start_instrument.xls", $missing, $missing, $missing, $missing, 
#                               $missing, $missing, $missing, $missing, $missing,
#                               $missing, $missing, $missing, $missing, $missing)

#   $wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open("d:\temp\start_instrument.xls", $missing, $missing, $missing, $missing, 
#                               $missing, $missing, $missing, $missing, $missing,
#                               $missing, $missing, $missing, $missing, 1)

    $XlCorruptLoad = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCorruptLoad" -as [type] 

    $wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open("d:\temp\start_instrument.xls", $missing, $missing, $missing, $missing, 
                                $missing, $missing, $missing, $missing, $missing,
                                $missing, $missing, $missing, $missing, $XlCorruptLoad::xlRepairFile)    
}
catch
{
    Write $Error[0].ToString()
}

# some stuff

if ($excel -ne $null)
{
    $excel.Quit()   

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
    $excel = $null
}

[System.GC]::Collect() | Out-Null
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers() | Out-Null
```

I have not idea why error occurs. I'll be glad to any advices and assumptions!

Comment: If you need to use `CorruptLoad` why have you not specified it in the argument list? You have it as `$missing`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193596.aspx.

Comment: @Matt, I tried all variants of calling `Open` function. I changed my code sample to show it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After much playing around with your PowerShell script... it's all very odd.

## Observed Behaviour

Firstly, the Open method on the Workbooks object only reports 14 parameters when `$excel.Workbooks.Open.Invoke.ToString()` is run. The ouptut reads:

```
Workbook Open (string, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant)
```

However, there is some kind of overload method for 15 parameters because, when using the more verbose error read-out `$Error[0]|format-list -force` i did two test calls, the first with 15 parameters and the second with 16.

**15 Parameters**

```
Exception             : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Unable to get the Open property of the Workbooks class
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.MethodInfoCallInstruction.InvokeInstance(Object instance, Object[] args)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstructionN.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

**16 Parameters**

```
Exception             : System.Management.Automation.MethodException: Cannot find an overload for "Open" and the argument count: "16" --->
                        System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Cannot find an overload for "Open" and the argument count: "16"
                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                           at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception
                        exception)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

As you can read above, the method does support 15 parameters but not 16. However, no matter what values are supplied to the 15th parameter, it will fail to open the file.

For the record, it works with 14 or less arguments, it is only the 15th argument that throws the exception.

## Conclusion

From everything that I've seen, I can only conclude that there is a problem with the Excel COM interop support in powershell. Supplying the 15th parameter as `$missing` simply should not change behaviour according to the [Workbooks.Open() reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194819.aspx). There being a problem with Powershell's Excel COM support is further reinforced because, when the VBA script is run as a macro, everything works as per the documentation.

## Suggested Next Steps

The first work-around that comes to mind is to write the VBA script as a macro and store it in an excel file that is used specifically for running VBA scripts from the command line. It would take minimal effort to implement and it is known by testing from both the OP and myself that it will work.

If you have any difficulty triggering the macro from powershell, see [Calling Excel macros from PowerShell with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536241/calling-excel-macros-from-powersheel-with-arguments)

Comment: Peter, thank you for idea with macros from another file! And with Excel COM component there are intresting situation: on another server with `Office 2010` SP2, powershell 2.0 and `.NET Framework 4.0` such problem doesn't occur.

Comment: @Indian I don't have any comparable environments so I can't confirm this. We do have quite considerable evidence of a bug; so, if you wish, you could submit it to Microsoft here: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell The information in my answer should provide a good basis for the bug report.