# How to get PowerShell to supress read-only mode, and allow editing when opening Excel workbook?

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm very new to PowerShell, my apologies in advance if I'm missing something obvious.

With my PowerShell script I want to do the following to a particular Excel file:

- Open that file.
- Refresh that file's data connection.
- Save that file.
- Then close that file.

An issue that I run into when I do this is that this file has some protections in place where I have to specifically select the option to open the file in edit mode, as seen below.

[image]

I've tried numerous suggestions, similar to what's been recommended in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170700/powershell-ignore-read-only-request-and-open-without-read-only) but the file always seems to remain in read-only mode, and I'm unable to save the file.

This is the code that I've created so far. If you have any suggestions on how I can open this file in read/write mode - your suggestions are welcomed.

```
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application

$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

$FilePath = "C:\....\....\etc\chosen_file.xlsx"

$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath, $null, $true)

$excel.Visible = $true

$connections = $workbook.Connections
$workbook.RefreshAll()

$excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs($FilePath) 
$workbook.Close()
$excel.quit()
```

Comment: `$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath, $null, $true)` - here the third parameter corresponds to read-only, so why are you using `$true`?

Comment: Hi @BigBen - I've also used $false in the third parameter but it doesn't make a difference, it's still read-only.

Comment: The 7th parameter is *IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended*... I'd use `$true` for that as well. (and `$false` for the 3rd parameter).

Comment: @BigBen - do you know how I declare parameters 4-6? I've tried just with '$null' but that throws an error:   "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108 
(RPC_E_DISCONNECTED))"

Comment: Try using `[Type]::Missing`.

Comment: For anyone who comes along later, the details of the third and seventh parameter can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbooks.Open. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [`Workbooks.Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open?view=excel-pia):

- The 3rd parameter is *ReadOnly* and should be `$false`.
- The 7th parameter is *IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended* and should be `$true`.
- Use `[Type]::Missing` for the 4th-6th parameters.

```
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath, $null, $false, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, [Type]::Missing, $true)
```