# SharePoint File opening as Read Only

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, sharepoint-2013

This is my 1st post here :)

I am writing a powershell code that triggers a macro in an Excel workbook.

The code works just fine, but I have an issue that the code openes the file as a Read Only. The problem does not occur, when I open the file manually.

When I tried to get isReadOnly value, Powershell advised me that the specific file does not have such a value. I tried also Trust Center and Antivirus solutions as per Microsoft website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/files-open-as-read-only-and-cannot-check-in-or-out).

I tried also solution from here: [How to get PowerShell to supress read-only mode, and allow editing when opening Excel workbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70775483/how-to-get-powershell-to-supress-read-only-mode-and-allow-editing-when-opening) , without any effect

```
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application  
 
$FilePath = 'SharePoint/testTest.xlsm'
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$excel.Visible = $true  

$app = $excel.Application
$app.Run("Macro1") 
$excel.Quit()
```

Can I somehow force opening it as editable?

Comment: Does your `$FilePath` contain `...sharepoint.com/:x:/r/`?

Comment: Yes - I checked the path, it works fine, as the file itself opens.

Comment: If so, change `..sharepoint.com/:x:/r/foldername` to `..sharepoint.com/foldername` - as the /r/ tells it to open read-only.