# Can VBA macro or function call or exec by Windows command?

Tags: excel, vba, windows, command

I am trying to call VBA function by windows command. Is it possible?
Or I have to make this happend via python?
If it's possible, Can I call it with parameters?

Comment: Did you attempt to research this yourself first? I know I see questions about people troubleshooting their implementations pretty often, so I imagine there's a lot out there to reference

Comment: Yes , but I find only VBA calling command, not command calling VBA.

Comment: [C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-calling-code-from-vba-in-a-visual-csharp-project?view=vs-2017), [VB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-calling-code-from-vba-in-a-visual-basic-project?view=vs-2017), [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19616205/2727437), [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536241/calling-excel-macros-from-powershell-with-arguments), [batch (ugly)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e166e9a1-cd30-43f4-9a75-8054762dc671/run-macro-using-batch-file?forum=exceldev) ... take your pick