# Running Excel Macro from Powershell/Powershell Core suddenly give 0x800A03EC error

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, powershell-core

I simplified the problem for the purpose of this question:

I have a file `Return13.xlsm` with following macro content:

```
Function Return13() As Integer
   Return13 = 13
End Function
```

And following Powershell script:

```
$E = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
[Void]$E.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyMagicalFolder\Return13.xlsm")
$x = $E.Run("Return13")
```

In both Powershells I get following error:

```
Exception calling "Run" with "1" argument(s): "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"
```

For the record - the functionality worked ~1month ago fine.
Now - the only semi-constructive feedback on the matter I found on the "web" is that one of Windows Updates could brake it but I have no idea how to find it and what to do about it - given I work in enteprise environment and can't undo this patch (and I would have to do it on more than just my personal dev machine).

Any ideas?

For the record I have Windows 8.1 64bit with Office 365 32bit. Powershell Core used is 64bit and old Powershell 32bit.

Comment: Check the file permissions and ensure you have read/write/execute. Also, make sure the worksheet is not protected.

Comment: Excel object model is enabled, all macros are allowed to run, file permissions are fine. The workbook is freshly crafted (new -> alt+f11 -> macro above -> save) so there's no protection on nothing.

Comment: If that changes anything the wbscript gives the same error

Comment: Try: $x = $E.Run('ThisWorkbook.Return13') cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536241/calling-excel-macros-from-powershell-with-arguments

Comment: @Tragamor thanks for suggestion - however the module prefix is not needed most of the time and haven't helped here either.